# Are these Startup event handlers identical?

Tags: c#, silverlight

I'm working on a Silverlight project and I'm trying to understand the differences between the following:

```
this.Startup += new StartupEventHandler(this.Application_Startup);
this.Startup += this.Application_Startup;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are identical.  The difference is just syntactic sugar: the compiler is automatically wrapping the function in a delegate in the second case.

This has been around since .NET 2.0; prior to that only the first case would have compiled.

Answer (score 3):

These are the same, the second line is a little syntax sugar - the compiler will wrap Application_Startup method into the delegate StartupEventHandler automatically.